# Trying to get an SVGZ file to display locally

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, firefox

I'm doing local development of some web pages, before posting them online.

SVGs inside `<img>` tags show up just fine, in both Firefox and Chrome. SVGZs do not. However they do show up okay when I actually post my files to the web and they're viewed non-locally. How do I configure my system so that SVGZs show up on a local page? (Linux Mint, if it matters. The SVGZs in question were created with Inkscape, and I've inspected them to make sure that they're valid.)

I've already tried adding this local `mime.types` file:

```
image/svg+xml svg svgz
```

and this local `.htaccess file`:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

As near as I can tell, these had no effect.

Thank you.

Comment: What local web server are you running?

Comment: None, to my knowledge. I'm just trying to read local files.

Comment: Then that's your problem. As you've discovered browsers don't support that so you need to run a local webserver and access your files that way.

Comment: Sorry--I think I might have misparsed "that's your problem". I put an angry response here, that I just deleted. (I've had issues with people on Stack Overflow being snarky and trying to one-up people.) I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt. Thanks.

Comment: Writing is harder to parse than speech I guess. I meant that we've identified the issue. You might want to edit the question to indicate tht you're trying to directly read local files without a web server. I can delete my first comment then.

Answer (score 1):

As .svgz files are just gziped .svg files, you can uncompress them for testing.

`gzip -cd file.svgz > file.svg`

All modern Webservers should be configured to use some sort of Transfer encoding. So there usualy is no need to upload .svgz ... if you still need .svgz anyways, to recompress them:

`gzip file.svg`

This will result in a file.svg.gz, rename it to file.svgz and you are good to go...

Comment: That would involve some seriously annoying scripting, to go back and forth constantly. Thanks though.

Comment: Alternatively Install a simple Test server that can Serve folder content... I use  https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve for this...